# Error comparision - Binary operator == cannot be applied two Error operands

Tags: ios, swift

I have got an error  as follows

Service Error is as follows:

```
enum ServiceError: Error {
  case ServerDown
  case UserNotExist
}
```

My error object is as follows

[image]

However, I am getting in the following comparision

> Binary operator == cannot be applied two Error operands

Are there any other better solution rather than adding Equatable solution in my case?

```
if error != nil {
  if error == ServerDown {
    print("ServerDown")
  } else if error == UserNotExist {
    print("User Not Exist")
  } else {
    print("Generic Error")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `Swift.Error` to your custom `ServiceError`. The common approach is to use a switch:

```
enum ServiceError: Error {
  case serverDown, userNotExist
}
```

---

```
let error: Error? = ServiceError.serverDown as Error

switch error as? ServiceError {
case .serverDown: print("Server is down")    // "Server is down\n"
case .userNotExist: print("User not found")
case .none: print("error:", error ?? "nil")
}
```

Note: It is Swift naming convention to name your enumeration cases starting with a lowercase letter.